# Python: Only return matching values in up to three lists but ignore empty lists

Tags: python, list, inner-join

I've created three lists of integers (a, b and c) and these may or may not contain any values. I want to create a new list (newList) based on these existing lists:

- If all three lists contain values, I want to populate newList with only the values that are common to every list (e.g. a = [1,2,3], b = [2,3,4], c = [3,4,5] then newList = [3])
- If all of the lists are empty, I want newList to also be empty (e.g. a = [], b = [], c = [] then newList = [])
- If one or two of the lists are empty, I want to populate newList with the values that the non-empty lists share (e.g. a = [], b = [2,3,4], c = [3,4,5] then newList = [3,4]

What I'm finding tricky is that any or none of the lists could be empty, meaning that I'm currently having to duplicate my code in different if statements.

The below is what I have tried but it looks really inefficient.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [3,4,5]

newList = []

if len(a) + len(b) + len(c) != 0:
    if len(a) > 0:
        if len(b) > 0:
            if len(c) > 0:
                #a, b and c all contain values, find common values
                newList = list(set(a) & set(b) & set(c))
            else:
                #a and b contain values, c is empty. Find common values in a and b.
                newList = list(set(a) & set(b))
        else:
            if len(c) > 0:
                #a and c contain values, b is empty. Find common values in a and c.
                newList = list(set(a) & set(c))
            else
                #only a contains values. b and c are empty.
                newList = a
    else:
        if len(b) > 0:
            if len(c) > 0:
                #b and c contain values, a is empty. Find common values in b and c.
                newList = list(set(b) & set(c))
            else:
                #only b contains values. a and c are empty
                newList = b
        else len(c > 0:
            #only c contains values. a and b are empty
            newList = c
else:
    #no lists contain values, leave newList as empty
```

I'd be really grateful if anyone has any improvements, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could approach it like this, generalized, and using sets:

```
def inner_join_nonempty(*iterables):
    sets = (set(iterable) for iterable in iterables)
    nonempty_sets = [s for s in sets if s]
    return set.intersection(*nonempty_sets) if nonempty_sets else set()
```

Usage for your example:

```
>>> inner_join_nonempty(a, b, c)
{3}
```